# What is the Bitcoin Friday?

Tags: websites, history, promotion

Recently the [Bitcoin Friday](http://bitcoinfriday.com/) event was announced. What is it all about?

Answer (score 2):

[Bitcoin Friday](http://bitcoinfriday.com/) is an event coordinated by some of the biggest Bitcoin sites, including MtGox, BitInstant and SatoshiDice to bring big discounts to Bitcoin users on their sites. The event will take place on Friday, 2012 11 09.